# How to show a resource group including its resources

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

This is a slightly stupid question! that I can't quite remember the answer to.

if you try to create a new resource group, where one already exists and then don't update it when prompted you get an output like this

```
ResourceGroupName : DjangoCMS
Location          : westeurope
ProvisioningState : Deleting
Tags              : 
Resources         : 
                    Name           Type                                 Location  
                    =============  ===================================  ==========
                    DJangoCMSnic1  Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces  westeurope
                    PublicIP1      Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses  westeurope
                    DJangoNet      Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks    westeurope

ResourceId        : /subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/DjangoCMS
```

I am sure that there is a cmdlet that gives that output, but I can't for the life of me find it! Can anyone help a clearly ailing memory...

Specifically I am looking for the thing that gives the above output, it may have been an old cmdlet that has changed what it outputs but it would be nice to know. (I'm not going mad)

Answer (score 1):

`Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupNameContains TESTNAME` works, but the output format is not like what you want. It lists the resources one by one:

```
Name              : derektest
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/a679c265-5ef2-48fe-8378-5f435b48536b/resourceGroups/VS-derektest-Group/providers/microsoft.visualstudio/account/derektest
ResourceName      : derektest
ResourceType      : microsoft.visualstudio/account
ResourceGroupName : VS-derektest-Group
Location          : australiaeast
SubscriptionId    : a679c265-5ef2-48fe-8378-5f435b48536b
Tags              : {}

Name              : derektest/TPtest
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/a679c265-5ef2-48fe-8378-5f435b48536b/resourceGroups/VS-derektest-Group/providers/microsoft.visualstudio/account/derektest/pro
                    ject/TPtest
ResourceName      : derektest/TPtest
ResourceType      : microsoft.visualstudio/account/project
ResourceGroupName : VS-derektest-Group
Location          : northcentralus
SubscriptionId    : a679c265-5ef2-48fe-8378-5f435b48536b
```

As for `Get-AzureRmResource`, it worked fine in previous build, but not working currently. Maybe it's an issue needs to be fixed. See details [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1259).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for:

```
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupNameContains TESTNAME
```

Doc for it is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/).

Comment: That gives the same information, but (I am sure) there is something that gives the output above. It may have been an old version of `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup` I just remember finding it really useful at some point and frustrated that I can't find it again!

Comment: I will confirm this with the team, but `(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "SOME_NAME").Resources.Count` always returns 0, so my hunch is that this particular property is deprecated.

Comment: This behavior was removed with the switch to the 1.x cmdlets and the "new way" of doing it is not working at the moment, see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1683 - I miss that capability dearly.  I like your work around of doing New-AzureRMResourceGroup -Force :)